# Add additional Rows in PHP

Tags: php

I need to add a button to add more rows, maybe 10 at a time? I also need each added row to have it's own variable name right? So it will echo out in the email template below? Or can it just be a bunch of fields to echo out? I have a team of non-programmers that will be using this form to print out the email template below it, so they can copy and paste. Would really be nice if it could have a button to copy to clipboard, but thats not the main issue.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Remove Bad Links Template</title>

<style>
body {font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif; color:#333; }
#wrapper { width:75%; margin:0 auto; background:#f2f2f2; border:#ccc; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow:3px 3px 3px #ccc; padding:20px; }
#emailback { background: #fff; padding:20px; }
h1, h2 { color:#0074b9; }
</style>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hammersmith+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>


<?php 
$name = $_GET['name'];
$link1 = $_GET['link1'];
$link2 = $_GET['link2'];
$link3 = $_GET['link3'];
$link4 = $_GET['link4'];
$link5 = $_GET['link5'];
$link6 = $_GET['link6'];
$link7 = $_GET['link7'];
$link5 = $_GET['link8'];
$link6 = $_GET['link9'];
$link7 = $_GET['link10'];
?>

<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Use the following template to request bad link removal</h1>

<form action="" method="GET">
<h3>WEBMASTERS NAME: <input type="text" name="name"></h3>
<h3>BAD LINK 1 <input type="text" name="link1"></h3>
<h3>BAD LINK 2 <input type="text" name="link2"></h3>
<h3>BAD LINK 3 <input type="text" name="link3"></h3>
<h3>BAD LINK 4 <input type="text" name="link4"></h3>
<h3>BAD LINK 5 <input type="text" name="link5"></h3>
<h3>BAD LINK 6 <input type="text" name="link6"></h3>
<h3>BAD LINK 7 <input type="text" name="link7"></h3>
<h3>BAD LINK 8 <input type="text" name="link8"></h3>
<h3>BAD LINK 9 <input type="text" name="link9"></h3>
<h3>BAD LINK 10 <input type="text" name="link10"></h3>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<p>


<h2>THEN COPY AND PASTE THE FOLLOWING AFTER SUBMITTING THE ABOVE FORM: </h2>

<div id="emailback">
Hi <?php echo $name; ?>, </p>
<p>
We have recently received a notification from Google stating that our website has unnatural links pointing towards it. This has really damaged our rankings on Google and as a result, we're trying to clear things up. Our website url is http://********.com.
</p><p>
We noticed the following links are pointing to our website from your site:
</p><p>
<h3><?php echo $link1; ?></h3>
<h3><?php echo $link2; ?></h3>
<h3><?php echo $link3; ?></h3>
<h3><?php echo $link4; ?></h3>
<h3><?php echo $link5; ?></h3>
<h3><?php echo $link6; ?></h3>
<h3><?php echo $link7; ?></h3>
<h3><?php echo $link8; ?></h3>
<h3><?php echo $link9; ?></h3>
<h3><?php echo $link10; ?></h3>
</p><p>
I appreciate this is inconvenient and isn't a reflection on your website at all, but if you're able to remove the links, we would really appreciate it and would be very grateful.
</p><p>
I look forward to hearing from you.
</p><p>
Jerry *****
</p><p>
*********
</p>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, post your code here. Stack Overflow can fit it.

Comment: What do you mean? I pasted code into Pastebin, but ok:

Comment: $name = $_GET['name'];
$link1 = $_GET['link1'];



<form action="" method="GET">
<h3>WEBMASTERS NAME: <input type="text" name="name"></h3>
<h3>BAD LINK 1 <input type="text" name="link1"></h3>
<input type="submit">
</form>


<h2>THEN COPY AND PASTE THE FOLLOWING AFTER SUBMITTING THE ABOVE FORM: </h2>

Hi <?php echo $name; ?>, </p>

<h3><?php echo $link1; ?></h3>

Comment: No, not in the comments. Click "edit" on your question and add the code in there. Then, highlight all the lines and click the "Code" button.

Comment: I had to cut out most of the code, as it would not fit, but perhaps you get the idea

Comment: Oh, we commented at the same time. Read my previous comment. Also, this solution will probably require JavaScript more than PHP.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46259/discussion-between-jerry-lee-and-nobleuplift)

Comment: Do not include content directly from `$_GET` without escaping it! You should rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, let's start with some [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) work.

```
<?php
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : 'Webmaster';
$links = $_GET['links'] ? $_GET['links'] : array_fill(0, 10, '');


if (isset($_GET['add-rows'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $links[] = '';
    }
}
?>
```

And then modify your form:

```
<form method="GET">
<h3>WEBMASTERS NAME: <input type="text" name="name"></h3>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($links); $i++) {
    echo '<h3>BAD LINK ' . ($i + 1) . ' <input type="text" name="links[]"></h3>';
}
?>
<input name="add-rows" type="submit" value="Add Rows">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And finally, change how your links output:

```
<p>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($links); $i++) {
    echo '<h3>' . $links[$i] . '</h3>';
}
?>
</p>
```

Comment: that's awesome, saves a lot of work. So how do I allow them to add more rows if needed?

Comment: This works on my local! Make sure to accept my answer if it works for you.

Comment: it's not echoing the results out for the links on mine. what are you using for that?

Comment: Your <form> should be submitting to the same page that the form is located on. Is it?

Comment: Make sure to click the hollow check mark to the left of my answer. That will make it accepted and finalize the question.